# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined at HTMLAnchorElement.linkAction

Tags: javascript, function

Showing me this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined at HTMLAnchorElement.linkAction
```

```js
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')

function linkAction(){
    // Active 
    
    navLink.forEach(n => n.classList.remove('active'))
    this.classlist.add('active')

    // remove menu mobile
    const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu')
    navMenu.classList.remove('show')
}
```

Comment: Showing me this === Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.linkAction

Comment: Next time please put the question in the question, and format your code.

Comment: how is `linkAction()` being called?

Comment: its a function to hide side nav on clicking on menus option

Comment: I can see that. Are you going to answer my question? How is `linkAction()` being called?

Comment: i did;nt understand what you are trying to ask>>!!

Comment: Well if you can't put in the effort that I won't either.

Comment: its simply called in function

Comment: should i add full code of javascript ?

Comment: The problem is `this` may or may not exist at all depending on exactly how the function is called. I can't help without seeing how the function is caled.

Comment: function is not called in html its just called in app.js

Comment: S H O W   M E . . .

Comment: what you want to see ????? Code ???????

Comment: Please be pacient with @MuhammadAnas as he is a **new contributor**, hence we forgive him (this time, he he  ). Also, we all should put our efforts in presenting **answers** and **solutions** to problems, instead of 'answering' with more questions. That is what stack is all about: **answers and solutions to problems**. See **solution** underneath ...

Comment: @MuhammadAnas. I want to see ***how the function is called***. It's not a trick question dude. I'm not sure how to be more specific. Do you not know what it means to call a function? I honestly don't know how to ask that question any clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

1. **Typo**: `classList` is **case-sensitive**:
   You have `this.classlist.add('active')`
   However, even correcting this typo wouldn't make code work, see point 2.
2. **Missing argument** at `linkAction()`:
   add the `event` as argument, in order to identify later which `element` triggered the function.

Hence, in your **html**: `onclick="linkAction(event)"`
then,  in your **JS**: `function linkAction(event){ ... event.target.classList.add('active')}`

Following complete code sample: **Run code snippet** and see result:

```js
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link');

// moved const assignment here outside of function
const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu'); 

function linkAction(event){
    // Active
    navLink.forEach(n => n.classList.remove('active'));

    // Typo: classList is case-sensitive
    // this.classlist.add('active'); 


    // following line does the trick :-)
    event.target.classList.add('active'); 

    // remove menu mobile
    
    // better define 'const navMenu' outside this function
    // to avoid multiple assignments

    navMenu.classList.remove('show');
}
```

```css
.nav__link {
  color: #333;
  margin: 1em;
  background: #eee;
}
.nav__link:hover {
  color: green;
  background: #ddd;
}
.nav__link.active {
  color: green;
  background: lime;
}

#nav-menu {
  display: none;
  color: #333;
  margin: 1em;
  background: #eee;
}
#nav-menu.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>click on any menu item below to trigger function</div>

<ul>
  <li class="nav__link" onclick="linkAction(event)">item 1 with class "nav__link"</li>
  <li class="nav__link" onclick="linkAction(event)">item 2 with class "nav__link"</li>
  <li class="nav__link" onclick="linkAction(event)">item 3 with class "nav__link"</li>
</ul>

<div class="show" id="nav-menu">
Mobile menu
  <ul>
    <li class="nav__link" onclick="linkAction(event)">Mobile item 1</li>
    <li class="nav__link" onclick="linkAction(event)">Mobile item 2</li>
    <li class="nav__link" onclick="linkAction(event)">Mobile item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did you get this markup from? How do you know this is being called from HTML, or that it's even an event handler? I asked half a dozen times how this function was called and OP refused to answer... It's generally considered bad practice to make assumptions like this.

Comment: He's obviously new to programming. If you make assumptions and your assumptions are wrong you could just confuse him further. That's why you should ask for clarification before posting an answer. You're not doing anyone any good by virtue signalling.

Comment: @MuhammadAnas Please let us know whether above code was any helpful (when function is called from HTML, i.e. click on menu-item, adding `event` handler) or advice otherwise. As you are a new contributor, please bear in mind that you can mark an answer as **accepted answer** if you feel it solved your issue, so that other contributors know that your issue has been solved and can concentrate on other question - thank you.